# jquery detect change inside div get the html and set to value of input

Tags: jquery, quill

i am using Quilljs, as a rich text editor.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //get content of quillEdit and insert into hidden input field.
    $(".ql-editor").on('change', function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        $("#QuillEdit").val(content);
        console.log(content);
    });
});
<form>
   <input type="text" name="quillEdit" id="QuillEdit" class="hidden-input" value="" />
</form>
<div id="quillEditor">
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
</div>
```

In the above, quill creates the editor inside #quillEditor.
in that, it creates a div with a class of ql-editor.

inside that div, all content (p tags etc) is created.

I am trying to, when ever a change happens inside ql-editor, then i want to dump that html into my input "QuillEdit" as its value..

but absolutely nothing is happening...

been drawing a blank with this so far. 
Any idea how to get it to work ?

Comment: Try: `$('.ql-editor').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
});`. instead of `$(".ql-editor").on('change', function() { });`. Unsure if it'll work, but that's what I'd try at least.

Comment: @Martin found out quilljs had a textchange event, i could hook onto.. totally missed it, when i tried looking through their documentation... But thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Yeah no poblem, but like I said, I was actually unsure if It'd work, which is why I chose to put it as a comment instead of an actual answer, but that's what came out of the top of my head. Instead of `.bind()` you can also use `.on()` depending on jQuery version. Saw you used `on()`, so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, quilljs has a textchange event, i can check on.

so my solution looks like this:

```
quill.on('text-change', function (delta, oldDelta, source) {
    var content = $(".ql-editor").html();
    $("#QuillEdit").val(content);
});
```